# How to control Xcode time profiler stop at some line of code manually?

Tags: xcode, instruments

I am currently using Xcode built-in time profiler to debug what is blocking my main thread. So I am wondering is there any way (e.g `fataError` or something) to stop the time profiler at some point so that I analyse more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any way to set a breakpoint in Instruments. But you can focus on a specific part of the trace in the Time Profiler instrument by clicking inside the Time Profiler graph and dragging in the graph.

To measure task performance in your code, look at the documentation for the `OSSignposter` struct, which is part of the OSLog framework. The following article introduces the OSLog framework and has links to some WWDC videos on logging:

[OSLog and Unified logging as recommended by Apple](https://www.avanderlee.com/workflow/oslog-unified-logging/)